# What is the largest screen resolution that mainstream graphics cards and displays support

Tags: resolution

I'm working on a piece of software that displays content, such as video, and needs to be "aware" of the screen resolution to display the image correctly.

At the moment we have set a maximum of 4000px x 4000px for the screen resolution. Are there any mainstream screens that support a resolution higher than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4000 × 4000 is 16 MegaPixels

nVidia [says](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadroplex-7000-us.html)

> The Quadro Plex 7000 solution drives up to 36 megapixels

Of course it depends on what you mean by mainstream and what displays people will be using your software with in 5 years time.

Aren't some film-makers using 4K (4,096 × 2,160) cameras now? The RED Epic-X S35 records 5,120 × 2,700, The RED Epic 617 is planned to record 28,000 × 9,334.